# What is the most efficient and Pythonic way of calculating limsup/liminf in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

[Limsup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior) is defined as the supremum of a sequence onward. In other words, at the current moment one can look at the future values and get the maximum of them to create the limsup.

**Question**

What is the most efficient and Pythonic way of calculating limsup/liminf in pandas?

**My try**

I am calculating the limsup using a for loop which I am sure is not an efficient way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(2000)
y = np.cumsum(x)
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['value'])
df['lim_sup'] = 0
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 4))
for i in range(len(df)):
  df['lim_sup'].iloc[i] = df['value'].iloc[i:].max()

df['value'].plot(ax=ax)
df['lim_sup'].plot(ax=ax, color='r')
ax.legend(['value', 'limsup'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you defining the limsup/liminf for a finite sequence? According to what you are doing it seems you can just take the last element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse the values and use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to get the cumulative maximum from the bottom up:

```
df["suprema"] = df.loc[::-1, "value"].cummax()
```

This column should probably be referred to as the suprema for `m >= n`, rather than the limsup.